# Populating data from JSON using Javascript. Better code design approach?

Tags: javascript, json

I have kind of a situation in my project where I have to provide link to JSON and populate data from JSON in HTML DOM Elements..

Right now, I am doing it in following ways :

1. Get JSON data (custom sync function)
2. Parse JSON Data.
3. Populate JSON Data in to DOM elements using $.each method..

I want to know if there is any better approach to achieve this?

Done :

Better approach would be use of KnockoutJS like frameworks :-) Done the same.. Thanks all.

SPECIAL THANKS TO ONE DOWNVOTER :-) YOU ROCK :P

Comment: please elaborate the what you want to achieve

Comment: Show an example of the JSON, HTML and the JS code. Can you change the JSON/HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's a good idea to use JS templates. They allow you to keep your JS & HTML more separated and clean. For example, have a look on [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).